# To import WebDriverWait the correct way is to use selenium.webdriver.support.wait or selenium.webdriver.support.ui?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

```python
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Since I started using *Selenium* I've always used `ui` and I've always seen others using `ui` too, but I'm not finding it in the *Selenium* documentation and now *Pylance* is showing this alert:

```
"WebDriverWait" is not exported from module "selenium.webdriver.support.ui"
Import from "selenium.webdriver.support.wait" instead
```

Both seem to work, but I didn't find anything warning about which one will become obsolete or anything like that. I would like to understand better what is behind this subject!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the official documentation, you have to use:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

Refer:

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html